Minimum of closed proper convex function
Consider a function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-x & \text{where $x\leq0$}\\
\infty & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}.$$
Then $\mathrm{dom}\, f = (-\infty, 0]$ and the function $f$ is closed. It can be easily seen that $\min_{x \in \mathbb R} f(x) = f(0) = 0$ and for all $x_0 \in \mathrm{int}\, \mathrm{dom}\, f$, $f(x_0) > 0$. However, by the lower semi-continuity, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that for all $y \in U$, $f(y) > 0$. And also there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x_0, \varepsilon) \subset U$, where $B(x_0, \varepsilon)$ refers to the closed Euclidean ball which is centered at $x_0$ and has the radius of $\varepsilon$. Therefore for that ball, all $z \in B(x_0, \varepsilon)$ satisfy $f(z) > 0$. And by the definition of closure from Convex Analysis by Rockafellar,
$$\mathrm{cl}\, \mathrm{int}\, \mathrm{dom}\, f = \bigcap \{\mathrm{int}\, \mathrm{dom}\, f + B(0, \varepsilon)\mid \varepsilon>0\} = \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \bigg\{\bigcup_{x \in \mathrm{int}\, \mathrm{dom}\, f} B(x, \varepsilon)\bigg\}.$$
Therefore I think that for all $x' \in \mathrm{cl}\, \mathrm{int}\, \mathrm{dom}\, f = \mathrm{dom}\, f$, $f(x') > 0$. But $f(0) = 0$ so this is not true. Now I feel so dumb and don't know where I have messed up. Would you please help me?

It is not clear what you are asking. How did you end up concluding that $f(x')>0$ for all $x' \in \mathrm{cl}, \mathrm{int}, \mathrm{dom}, f$?

@copper.hat Because for all $x_0 \in \mathrm{int}, \mathrm{dom}, f$ there exist $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $x \in B(x_0, \varepsilon)$, $f(x) > 0$. And as the closure is the intersection, for all $\varepsilon' > 0$, of unions of all balls with radius of $\varepsilon'$, I concluded that $f(x') > 0$ for all $x' \in \mathrm{cl}, \mathrm{int}, \mathrm{dom}, f$. Is there anything wrong with my logic?

I mean, unions of all balls which have centers in $\mathrm{int}, \mathrm{dom}, f$ with radius of $\varepsilon'$.

I still do not follow your reasoning.

@copper.hat Sorry, my reasoning was so wrong, maybe that is why you didn't get what I was saying. I had the error similar to the Achilles and turtle paradox - there always exists a ball which does not intersect with boundary, then why the intersection of all of them meets with closure? But this is wrong because the union had to be done prior to the intersection, and there also always exists a ball which intersects with boundary. My mistake was to do intersection before the union, maybe that is because I relied my logics to my intuition too much.

*why the intersection of all of them meets with boundary?
sorry for miswriting

In the last RHS equality, the $\epsilon$ is fixed and the ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ may not be in the $\text {int dom} f$.

I feel so stupid haha. Thank you a lot!
